# Why page gets blank with "[Object]" after javascript:window.open?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I've put a link on one page that opens a new window.
the markup it's:

```
Click <a href="javascript:window.open('../SomePage.aspx', 'mynewwin', 'width=880,height=600,toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1');" >HERE</a>.
```

It happens that when I click the link, the new page shows perfect, but the old one gets blank and only "[Object]" it's writen on it. It should stay as it was.

It's weird!

Comment: Try adding "void(0);" to the end of the href, i.e. href="javascript:.....;void(0);"

Comment: @murdock: You're right. that works. But not an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @murdock You should write that as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are not cancelling the click action.

```
Click <a href="javascript:window.open('../SomePage.aspx', 'mynewwin', 'width=880,height=600,toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1');return false;" >HERE</a>
```

ideally you would not use the href to open the window.

```
<a target="_blank" href="../SomePage.aspx" onclick="window.open(this.href, 'mynewwin', 'width=880,height=600,toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1');return false;" >
```

even better would be to attach the link event in an unobtrusive manner.

Comment: You can't `return false;` like you have done in the `href` example. I believe it needs to be `void(0);`

Comment: Exactly. I had return false; but it also cancelled the new window opening.
Unfortunately I'm forced to use a link, as it is rendered in a hover message after saving the element. The funcionality it's: You've saved, if you wan't to print it click HERE. and then it opens a preview window.

Comment: @epascarello: wouldn't that somepage.aspx in href also redirect the main page? I want it to stay unaltered. I'll try it.

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: @epascarello: The second approach worked really nice.
Murdock & Blake solution also worked with less change to my expression. I can't really decide what's the one to approve. :(

Comment: If you want less code `<a href="#" onclick="window.open('../SomePage.aspx', 'mynewwin', 'width=880,height=600,toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1');return false;" >HERE</a>` With my answer above, if JS is disabled, the link still works. With yours, the other poster, and the one I put in this comment, they will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
        function myFunc()
        {
        window.open('../SomePage.aspx', 'mynewwin','width=880,height=600,toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1');
        }
    </script>

    <body>
        Click <a href="#" onclick="return myFunc();">HERE</a>

    </body>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HariprasadKamath/ckQjq/)

Comment: Is it about this post? I think it's http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20652696/plotting-data-in-pyqtgraph-with-qtdesigner, right? I will take care next time